# About a problem on Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability

Regarding a solved problem from one Book from Sheldon Ross as below:

**Problem:** Suppose that it is known that the number of items produced in a factory
during a week is a random variable with mean 50

b)If the variance of a week’s production is known to equal 25, then what can
be said about the probability that this week’s production will be between
40 and 60?

**The solution is as mentioned below:**

By Chebyshev’s inequality

$$P\{\lvert X - 50 \rvert \ge 10\} \le \frac {\sigma^2} {10^2} = \frac {1}{4} $$
Hence
$$P\{\lvert X - 50 \rvert \lt 10\} \ge 1-\frac{1}{4} = \frac {3}{4} $$
and so the probability that this week’s production will be between 40 and 60 is at
least .75

Assuming Chebyshev's inequality as:
$$P\{\lvert X - \mu \rvert \ge k\} \le \frac {\sigma^2} {k^2} $$

What I am unable to understand that why we took k as 10 ? also How above result comes for between 40 and 60?
Thank You

Comment: Because $|x|\lt a$ means $x\in(-a,+a)$ aka $-a\lt x \lt +a$.

Comment: @Vepir I got some hint that here a is 10 and x is x is X-50, but a detailed solution will help more

Comment: It is okay to answer your own questions if you figure it out. I'm not sure what more is there to say, just add $50$ to both sides of the two inequalities to get $X\in(50-k,50+k)$ to deduce $k=10$ in order to have $X\in(40,60)$.

Answer (score 0):

So, I can solve like this:

in $|X| \lt k$ If we take k = 10 we have
$|X| \lt 10 \Rightarrow X \in (-10,10) \Rightarrow -10 \lt X \lt 10$

$ \Rightarrow 50-10 \lt 50-X \lt 50+10 \Rightarrow 40 \lt 50-X \lt 60$

Now

$P\{\lvert X - 50 \rvert \ge 10\} \le \frac {1}{4}$ for week's production below 40(including) and above 60(including)

$ P\{\lvert X - 50 \rvert \lt 10\} \ge  \frac {3}{4}$ for week's production above 40(excluding) and below 60(excluding)

Please correct me if needed. Thanks

Comment: You need to revise your inequalities. Your last implication is not correct, you added $50$ to both sides of the two inequalities, but how did $X$ change sign? You also went in the wrong direction, you want to have $X$ in $(40,60)$, not $50-X$. But also, instead of "guessing $k$", its better to write $|X-50| \lt k$ iff $-k\lt X-50 \lt k$ iff  $50 - k\lt X \lt 50 + k$, then solve for $50-k=40, 50+k=60$ to get $k$.